# AVFAudio Framework not present on macOS causes warning for iOS app (app should also be available on AS Macs)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, frameworks

My iOS app uses the AVFAudio framework to provide spoken feedback to the user while running.  I would like this app to also run on Apple Silicon Macs (where the spoken feedback is not really necessary).

However, just importing the framework results in the following warning email after I upload to App Store Connect:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "App Name" 7.0 (24). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
> correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app links with
> libraries that are not present on Mac:
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/AVFAudio

I guess that this means the app will not be able to run on Macs.

How should I get this app to use the AVFAudio framework for iOS and still be available to run on macOS (AS Macs) with or without the framework on macOS?

Relevant code is:

```
import AVFoundation

class Speaker {

    var speechSynth: AVSpeechSynthesizer
    
    class func establishAudioSession() {
         do {
              try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [.interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers, .duckOthers])
              try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.voicePrompt)
              try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: [])
```

**UPDATE / CLARIFICATION:**

Note that my project does not include multiple targets.  With multiple targets, this would be fairly straightforward.  I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this by taking advantage of the newer AS Macs’ ability to run apps built for iOS without a separate target.

Is this possible when using this framework?

**UPDATE 2:**

I have submitted a support request to Apple for this now and their first suggestion was replacing

```
import AVFoundation
```

with

```
import AVFAudio
```

and then re-uploaded to App Store Connect, but after trying this, I get the same warning email back again.  Will post an update (or hopefully an answer) when I hear back from them again.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your project has multiple targets defines (i.e. one for iOS and one for macOS). In the "General" tag of your target settings you can select which frameworks should be included under "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content". Add your library for iOS, remove it for macOS.

If you share the same code you between apps you can also conditionally exclude some of it for macOS.

```
#if os(iOS)
// iOS only code
#endif
```

Comment: I guess that could be an option.  But no, at present there are not multiple targets.  I was hoping to take advantage of the newer AS Macs being able to run apps built for iOS without having to create an additional target.  I should update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Alright, that's weird since the framework should be available on macOS as well. At least for bridging.

Answer (score 1):

> However, just importing the framework results in the following warning email after I upload to App Store Connect:

The problem probably isn't importing, but (as the message you got indicates), *linking* to AVFAudio, that's the problem. So solve that, you should select your app target in the Xcode project and go to the Build Phases tab. Look at the **Link Binary with Libraries** line and hit the disclosure button at the beginning of the line to reveal all the libraries that are linked into your app. Find AVFAudio and change the setting (there's a popup on the right side of the line) from *Required* to *Optional*. That'll let your app link to the framework if it's there, but still run if it's not.

But wait, you're not done yet... What do you think will happen if your app tries to actually use a framework that's not linked in (because it doesn't exist on the machine)? You'll get a crash, of course. To avoid that unhappy fate, you'll need to check for the existence of the framework before you use it. For example, you could do something like:

```
if NSClassFromString("AVAudioPlayer") != nil {
    // do your AVFAudio stuff here
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't have the framework listed in the target settings at all, but the `import` alone seemed to be enough.  If I then explicitly listed in the build settings and set it to optional it did actually work.  So thanks for this advice.  I could then use something like `if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac` to avoid that code on the Mac.  Not sure how to handle the `import` line in that case, though.  HOWEVER, Apple have since come back to me with some further advice which I will now write up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Further follow up from Apple support suggested the following:

1. Change back to `import AVFoundation`
2. Reduce the deployment targets from the latest and greatest back down to something less recent.

So I did both of these, changing the deployment targets from iOS 14.5 and macOS 11.3 to iOS 14.1 and macOS 11.0.

This has resolved (or worked around!) the issue.

I do want to deploy to the latest and greatest target for this particular app, so I don't consider it to be a complete solution as yet, but it will do as a work around for now.  (I actually want to deploy to 15.0 when it's available to make use of the promised improvements to OSLogStore.)

So this sounds like a bug to me, and I have queried Apple for some further information on the issue, in particular, the ability to target more recent OS versions.